# React Native IOS application can not upload image through Express+ multer server

Tags: express, react-native, multer

React Native IOS application, want to upload image; from device.
RN 0.39.2

Client:

```
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('files', file)
formData.append('type', 'image')

fetch(API_HOST+UPLOAD_AVATAR,{
    method:'post',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data;boundary=6ff46e0b6b5148d984f148b6542e5a5d','Authorization': 'Bearer'+' '+token},
    body: formData
 })
 .then(response=>response.json())
 .then(data=>{
                      //console.log(data)
                      //Alert.alert(data)
  })
  .catch(error=>{
      console.log(error)
  })
```

Server :

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer();
router.post('/user', ensureAuthenticated, upload.any(), function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.files);
})
```

Error:

server req.body and req.files are empty.

Then I try to use RNFetchBlob.

```
     RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', API_HOST+UPLOAD_AVATAR, {
           'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data;boundary=6ff46e0b6b5148d984f148b6542e5a5d'
           'Authorization' : 'Bearer'+' '+token
     }, formData)
     .then((resp) => {

     }).catch((err) => {
         // ...
     })
```

then error change to

NSMutableDictionary cannot be converted to NSString.

And req.body is {}, req.files is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I assume you found a solution to this, if yes, could you share it?. 
In any case, for the RNFetchBlob issue, I used to get the same error and I solved by changing FormData to an array. Like this:

```
const body = [{
  name: 'data',
  data: JSON.stringify(whateverData)
}, {
  name: 'file',
  data: filePath,
}]; 

…

RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', apiEndpoint, headers, body);
```

Hope that helps.